# registers set by function

Tags: windows, debugging, anti-debugging

How can I figure out which general-purpose registers are modified by a function call. I am programming a Win32 Assembly program that calls IsDebuggerPresent(). According to MSDN, it will return a boolean value of nonzero is a debugger is present. How would I find out which register is modified without having to assemble and link the program to test it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, this concept is referred to as *register preservation* or *register volatility*.

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Register_preservation --

> According to the Intel ABI to which the vast majority of compilers
>   conform, the `EAX`, `EDX`, and `ECX` are to be free for use within a
>   procedure or function, and need not be preserved.

In other words, an API function such as `IsDebuggerPresent()` might modify `EAX`, `EDX`, and/or `ECX`, but it won't modify `EBX`, `ESP`, or `EBP`.